# Unable to detect stars and constellations in simulation of stars from the Hipparcos catalogue

Tags: star, coordinate, constellations

I am creating a planetarium program using Unity3D and C# to plot out stars from the Hipparcos catalogue. Using the Plx, _RA.icrs and _DE.icrs columns of the dataset, I have managed to work the distance in parsecs and work out a cartesian set of coordinates.

Simulation Class...

```
public class Simulation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IEnumerator loadStars()
    {
        starsLoaded = 0;
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        // Use the last frame duration as a guide how long one frame should take
        var targetMilliseconds = Time.deltaTime * 100f;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalStars; i++)
        {
            Double.TryParse(datasetTable[i, 3], out double test);
            if (!(datasetTable[i, 12] == null) && !(datasetTable[i, 13] == null) && !(datasetTable[i, 6] == null))
            {
                GameObject thisStar = Instantiate(starPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                thisStar.transform.parent = starHolder.transform;
                Int32.TryParse(datasetTable[i, 0], out (thisStar.GetComponent<Star>().ID));
                Double.TryParse(datasetTable[i, 12], out (thisStar.GetComponent<Star>().RA));
                Double.TryParse(datasetTable[i, 13], out (thisStar.GetComponent<Star>().DE));
                Double.TryParse(datasetTable[i, 3], out (thisStar.GetComponent<Star>().Vmag));
                Double.TryParse(datasetTable[i, 6], out (thisStar.GetComponent<Star>().Plx));
                Double.TryParse(datasetTable[i, 10], out (thisStar.GetComponent<Star>().CI));
            }
            if (stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > targetMilliseconds)
            {
                yield return null;
                stopWatch.Restart();
            }
            starsLoaded++;
        }
    }
}
```

Star class:

```
public class Star : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifier (HIP number). "HIP" is appended to the ID, for Hipparcos
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField] public int ID; // { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Right Ascension (J2000) in degrees. 
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField] public double RA; //{ get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Declination (J2000) in degrees. 
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField] public double DE; //{ get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Magnitude in Johnson V
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField] public double Vmag; //{ get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Trigonometric parallax, measured in milli-seconds of arc
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField] public double Plx; //{ get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Colour index in Johnson B-V colour
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField] public double CI; //{ get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Distance of the star from the centre of Earth measured in kilometres
    /// </summary> 
    [SerializeField] public double distanceFromEarth;
    /// <summary>
    /// Cartesian (X,Y,Z) positioning of the star
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField] Vector3 cartesianPositioning;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        positionStar();
    }

    private void distanceFromEarthCalc()
    {
        // Convert Plx from milliarcseconds to arcseconds (seconds of arc)
        double PlxSOA = Plx / 1000;
        // Calculate distance from equation d=1/p
        // distance d is measured in parsecs and the parallax angle p is measured in arcseconds.
        double dPC = 1 / PlxSOA;
        /// Convert parsecs to kilomentres
        /// Conversion can bbe found here:
        /// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsec
        /// 
        /// QUICK NOTE: converting to km causes issues with unity - values are too high
        ///             maybe work with parsecs instead?
        ///             
        //distanceFromEarth = (dPC * (96939420213600000 / math.PI_DBL)) / 1000;
        //distanceFromEarth = distanceFromEarth / 10000; // metres to kilometres
        distanceFromEarth = dPC * 10; // multiplied by 10 to move stars away from camera
    }


    private void cartesianPositioningCalc()
    {
        distanceFromEarthCalc();

        double RA_rad = RA * (math.PI_DBL / 180);
        double DE_rad = DE * (math.PI_DBL / 180);

        cartesianPositioning.x = (float)(distanceFromEarth * (math.cos(DE_rad)) * (math.cos(RA_rad)));
        cartesianPositioning.y = (float)(distanceFromEarth * (math.cos(DE_rad)) * (math.sin(RA_rad)));
        cartesianPositioning.z = (float)(distanceFromEarth * (math.sin(DE_rad)));
    }

    private void positionStar()
    {
        cartesianPositioningCalc();
        gameObject.transform.position = cartesianPositioning;
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2, 2, 2);
    }
}
```

View from the camera:
[image: View from the Unity camera]

3D view of the scene (the camera's orientation is shown by the arrows):
[image: 3D view of the scene]

With the image from the camera, I tried uploading it to http://nova.astrometry.net/ but was unable to find stars/constellations.

So I thought about normalising the vectors of the stars.

With the Simulation class unchanged, I changed the distanceFromEarth variable in the Star class to 900 to normalise the vectors (each star will not have the same distance from the centre)

View from the camera:
[image: View from the camera]

3D view of the scene (the camera's orientation is shown by the arrows):
[image: 3D view of the scene]

Even after the normalisation, uploading the image of the view from the camera to the image processing website resulted in no stars/constellations being detected.

What am I doing wrong, why aren't stars and constellation detected?

Comment: Try disregarding distance and set that to the same big one for each star. Scale visible size inversely to magnitude and / or limit to stars brighter than 5 mag. See weather all that combined gives you some results

Comment: My https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/92387/why-do-stars-appear-as-circles-not-points discusses the size of a star on photographic medium and may or may not be helpful

Comment: Quite helpful actually, this will come in handy when I start to create dynamic and unique models for each star

Answer (score 2):

The [apparent magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude) *m*=`Vmag` could be what's missing.
Stars of apparent magnitude *m*=0 should appear 100 times as bright as *m*=5 stars.
If you are simulating a naked-eye view, you can omit stars of *m*>6.

When you place stars at nonuniform distances, you'll need to compute [absolute magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_magnitude) *M* from apparent magnitude *m* and distance.
If *p*=`Plx` is parallax in milliarcseconds,

$$ M \approx m + 5 \log_{10}{p} - 10 $$

If all stars are modeled in the same (emissive?) material, the object representing a star of absolute magnitude *M*=0 should have 100 times the surface area, and 10 times the radius, as an *M*=5 star.

$$ r(M) = 10^{1-M/5} r(5) $$

To check your work, planetarium sites such as [TheSkyLive](https://theskylive.com/planetarium) or [Stellarium Web](https://stellarium-web.org/) would be less compute-intensive than uploading images to astrometry.net.

Comment: Is there any sort of mathematical formula that can be used to calculate the radius of these star objects, given their apparent magnitude and parallax/distance from Earth (calculated from the parallax values of each star)?

Comment: @SidS Updated with formulas.

Comment: I've implemented the formulas, however I don't think I've done it correctly as the stars are massive, please could you check it for me at this URL: https://pastebin.com/HYazJLq2 . Also, the maximum radius must be 5, how do I accomplish this.

Comment: I have completely updated the script to follow suit with your answer. The script is accessible from the same URL as above. I have opened a new question regarding this at this URL: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/36406/simulating-star-sizes-to-scale-given-the-magnitude-and-parallax-angle